# SQLAlchemy bulk insert in batches with DB generated defaults

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to implement the equivalent of Django's `MyModel.objects.bulk_create(new_mymodel_objects, batch_size=10000)` using SQLAlchemy.

I can use:

```py
engine = create_engine(settings.MY_DATABASE,
                executemany_mode='batch', executemany_batch_page_size=10000)
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session_maker()

def bulk_create_objects(model, instance_list):
    instances = [model(**instance) for instance in instance_list]
    return instances

def bulk_create_messages_for_mymodel(self, objects_list):
    objects = bulk_create_objects(MyModel, objects_list)
    with self.session.begin():
        self.session.bulk_save_objects(objects)

bulk_create_messages_for_mymodel(new_mymodel_objects)
```

But since there are fields in `MyModel` such as `id` which are being generated by the Postgres DB, I understand that `executemany` will not be as effective.

How can I implement this in a robust way for tables with DB generated values?

Comment: "since there are fields in MyModel such as id which are being generated by the Postgres DB, I understand that executemany will not be as effective" - do you have a source for this?

Comment: "We realized that SQLAlchemy only batches inserts if the primary keys are already defined on your model." - https://benchling.engineering/sqlalchemy-batch-inserts-a-module-for-when-youre-inserting-thousands-of-rows-and-it-s-slow-16ece0ef5bf7

Comment: This is because they set `return_defaults=True`.